# changing values of multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a few divs with IDs like "div1", "div2", "div3" and so on.

What I am doing now is:

```
document.getElementById('#div1').value='something';
document.getElementById('#div2').value='something';
document.getElementById('#div3').value='something';
```

but this gets annoying if I have like 30 divs. I'm trying to use "for" but it's not working:

```
for(var i=1; i<31; i++) {
    document.getElementById('#div'+i).value='something';
}
```

I'm getting the same thing when I use the .val() function (jQuery).

What am I doing wrong in this case, guys? :)

Comment: Are you adding the same value for each div?

Comment: Don't add the `#` in the `getElementById` argument

Comment: Divs don't have a value attribute.  They have an innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things wrong. first, don't use `#` in `getElementById()`. second is that `div` elements doesn't have `.value` attribute, use `innerHTML` instead.. the third is that you're trying to access multiple elements by their id instead of creating a class shared by all of them. Code example:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div2" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div3" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div4" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div5" class="myDiv"></div>
<div id="div6" class="myDiv"></div>
...
```

jQuery: (tagged in question - easiest example)

```
$(function(){
    $('.myDiv').text('something');
});
```

Comment: My example was not very good just for you guys to understand what I was doing. Everything is working fine now. Thank you, Yotam!

Answer (score 0):

You may use jquery each function but first you need to declare an array of div IDs for which you want to assign the value.

```
jQuery.each( [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ], function() {
$('#' + this).text('value');
});
```

Or as said by Yotam, you may give a common class and just write

```
$('.className').text('value');
```

Comment: its so hard to get even a singe thumbs up. [phew]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function textDiv() {
            var totalDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div").length 
            for(var i =0; i<totalDivs; i++)
            { 
                document.getElementById("div" + [i]).innerHTML = "Some Thing as a Text"

            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="textDiv();">
    <div id="div0"></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```